# Magento shipping method to product page

Tags: php, magento

I am new to Magento. Now I am customizing Magento built-in theme. I want to add available shipping info to the product view page. Please help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will not get shipping method unless haven't specify any parameter like country,pincode or state.

Below url give you fair idea about shipping method on product page

http://www.ecomdev.org/2010/06/22/estimate-the-product-shipping-rate-on-its-
page.html